# Return products which belong to all tags in a list using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a service method which accepts a delimited list of tags and is supposed to return a list of products which are assigned to all tags in that list.

This is what I have, and it returns no products. I've double-checked the data, there IS a product that belongs to two tags.

```
public List<Product> GetTagProducts(string tags)
{
    //list of parameters
    var tagParams = tags.Split('+').ToList();

    //return all products which belong to ALL tags specified in tagParams list
    return (from pt in _repository.ProductTags
            where tagParams.All(p => p == pt.Tag.Name)
            select pt.Product).Distinct().Take(75).ToList();
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Short Description")]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Long Description")]
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTag
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductTagId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Tag")]
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

//Repository
private DatabaseContext _context = new DatabaseContext();
public IQueryable<ProductTag> ProductTags
    {
        get { return _context.ProductTags; }
    }
```

**EDIT**: to clarify the result I'm looking for.  Lets say tagParams holds two tag strings (meaning I am searching for products tagged with BOTH of these):

```
Automotive
General
```

And lets say we have the following products:

```
product             tags
-------             ----
Wipers              Automotive, General
Air Freshener       General
Gloves              General
Tires               Automotive
Mirror              Automotive, General
```

The query should return "Wipers" and "Mirror".

Comment: Right, updated question to show classes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method chain style:

```
List<Product> allProducts = GetAllProductsFromSomewhere();
allProducts.Where(p => tagParams.All(tag => 
p.Tags.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(tag))).Distinct().Take(75).ToList();
```

`All` means that all of the tags should equal to one tag. And you said it contains two tags, So it's impossible.
In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) words:

> Determines whether **all** elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

Comment: Thanks gdoron, but his does not return the correct result. It returns products that belong to any of the tags, not products that belong to all of them. I've edited my question to clarify the result I need.

Comment: @JohnL. Show the classes as well. what does `_repository.ProductTags` looks like?

Comment: @JohnL. I still don't know the `_repository` looks like but it should be something like the updated answer.

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood the comment. I've updated my post. The repository code is at the bottom of the code listing.

Comment: @JohnL. Just change the `allProducts` to the way you get the list of Products from you repository.

Comment: This compiles but results in a runtime error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.TagProduct'".  Weird, since my table is called ProductTag.

Comment: @JohnL. If you got a specific question I could try help you with it. I feel like in a "ping-pong" game...

Comment: So I inspected the HTML created by the LINQ, and its incorrect. If I make corrections to the HTML, it works fine and returns the correct data, so it seems your LINQ is correct (or at least helpful).  I created a separate post here [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086670/linq-generates-incorrect-html-reference-to-a-non-existent-table, and accepted your answer. Thanks for your help!