# LINQ generates incorrect SQL (reference to a non-existent table)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4, ef-model-first

MVC3 project, using LINQ to Entity, and Entity Framework 4 Code-First.

In another post ( [Return products which belong to all tags in a list using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074875/return-products-which-belong-to-all-tags-in-a-list-using-linq) ), I received assistance in creating a LINQ statement to return a subset of data.

The LINQ is syntactically correct and compiles, but generates incorrect SQL.  Specifically, it makes reference to a non-existent table.  If I correct the table name, it returns the correct data, so the LINQ seems to be correct.

Note in the interest of keeping this long post from getting even longer, I wont post the object classes (Product, Tag, and ProductTag), but they are listed in my previous question here: [Return products which belong to all tags in a list using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074875/return-products-which-belong-to-all-tags-in-a-list-using-linq)

**The LINQ:**

```
var tags = "administration+commerce"
var tagParams = tags.Split('+').ToList();   //used in linq statement below

_repository.Products.Where(p => tagParams.All(tag => p.Tags.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(tag))).Distinct().Take(75).ToList();
```

Following is the incorrect and correct SQL code.

The incorrect SQL makes references to non-existent table

```
[dbo].[TagProduct]
```

as well as a malformed field

```
[ExtentN].[Tag_TagId]
```

If I correct these to "[dbo].[ProductTag]" and "[ExtentN].[TagId]", the SQL executes correctly and returns the correct data.

**The LINQ-generated (and faulty) SQL**

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
[Extent1].[LongDescription] AS [LongDescription], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        N'administration' AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        N'commerce' AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
    WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[TagProduct] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[TagId] = [Extent2].[Tag_TagId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[Product_ProductId]) AND ([Extent3].[Name] = [UnionAll1].[C1])
    )) OR (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[TagProduct] AS [Extent4]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent5].[TagId] = [Extent4].[Tag_TagId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent4].[Product_ProductId]) AND ([Extent5].[Name] = [UnionAll1].[C1])
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[TagProduct] AS [Extent6]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent7].[TagId] = [Extent6].[Tag_TagId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent6].[Product_ProductId]) AND ([Extent7].[Name] = [UnionAll1].[C1])
    )) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL)
)
```

**The corrected SQL**

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[ShortDescription] AS [ShortDescription], 
[Extent1].[LongDescription] AS [LongDescription], 
[Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
FROM [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        N'administration' AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        N'commerce' AS [C1]
        FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]
    WHERE ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[ProductTag] AS [Extent2]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[TagId] = [Extent2].[TagId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent2].[ProductId]) AND ([Extent3].[Name] = [UnionAll1].[C1])
    )) OR (CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[ProductTag] AS [Extent4]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent5].[TagId] = [Extent4].[TagId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent4].[ProductId]) AND ([Extent5].[Name] = [UnionAll1].[C1])
    )) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[ProductTag] AS [Extent6]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tag] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent7].[TagId] = [Extent6].[TagId]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ProductId] = [Extent6].[ProductId]) AND ([Extent7].[Name] = [UnionAll1].[C1])
    )) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL)
)
```

Again, the only changes in the SQL is

```
[dbo].[TagProduct] changed to [dbo].[ProductTag]
[ExtentN].[Tag_TagId] changed to [ExtentN].[TagId]
```

Note I've ensured that the database has no object named dbo.TagProduct, and no references exist in my code to TagProduct (nor has it ever).

Is there a problem in my LINQ statement, or is this a LINQ bug? I'm ok with scrapping it altogether and just creating a stored-procedure, but I'd rather find a fix.

Thanks and apologies for the long post.

**EDIT**

The problem turned out to be a flawed entity model, with excessive and unnecessary navigation properties between the tables in a many-to-many relationship. Slauma's detailed answer was key in understanding what was happening.

The new model is as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    .
    . 
    //public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }             // <--removed
    public virtual List<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTag
{
    .
    . 
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    .
    . 
    //public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }      // <--removed
    public virtual List<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Um, that's not HTML... that's SQL... and it sounds like your model is probably out of date with your schema.

Comment: Looks like you changed your model without re-creating the database

Comment: You should have changed the wrong LINQ query to the corrected one I gave you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9074875/601179)...

Comment: Speechless over specifying HTML instead of SQL; edited post. Also, bad cut/paste in the chain method query. I had tried converting it to linq and thats what I came up with. Either way, both versions (including yours, gdoron) produces the same incorrect SQL and throws a runtime error. As for the model being out of date, at no point did I have a TagProduct table or model. I created dbo.ProductTag and its model just yesterday. So I dont believe its out of date...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have any additional mapping in Fluent API in the model in your linked post the generated SQL is correct and expected. Why?

To make it clear I copy your model with the relevant navigation properties and mark which belong together:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }         /* 1 */
    public virtual List<ProductTag> ProductTags { get; set; }   /* 2 */
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }                 /* 1 */
}

public class ProductTag
{
    public int ProductTagId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }                /* 3 */
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }                        /* 2 */
}
```

So, you have a **many-to-many** relationship (`/* 1 */`) between `Tag` and `Product`, a **one-to-many** relationship (`/* 2 */`) between `Tag` and `ProductTag` and a **one-to-many** relationship (`/* 3 */`) between `Product` and `ProductTag` where the navigation property in `Product` is not exposed.

Because you don't have a mapping for the many-to-many relationship in Fluent API Entity Framework will expect database tables which follow mapping conventions - and that is:

- A many-to-many join table called `ProductTags` **or** `TagProducts`. If you have disabled pluralization it will expect `ProductTag` **or** `TagProduct`. I say "**or**" because the name depends on factors like the order of the sets in your derived context and perhaps even the order of navigation properties in your classes, etc. So, it's difficult to predict the name in a complex model - basically the reason why it is recommended to define many-to-many relationships always explicitely in Fluent API.
- One key column in the table with name `EntityClassName_EntityKeyName` -> `Tag_TagId`
- The other key column in the table with `Product_ProductId`

In your query only this many-to-many relationship is involved (you are using only `Product.Tags` as the only navigation property in the query). So, EF will create a SQL query which includes the join table (it happens to be `TagProduct` in your case, but as said, only by accident) and the key column names of the join table which are `Tag_TagId` and `Product_ProductId`.

You can define the many-to-many mapping in Fluent API by:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
    .WithMany(t => t.Products)
    .Map(x =>
    {
        x.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
        x.MapRightKey("TagId");
        x.ToTable("ProductTag");
    });
```

This will create problems though because you already have a `ProductTag` entity which apparently already has the corresponding table `ProductTag`. This can't be the join table for your many-to-many relationship at the same time. The join table must have another name, like `x.ToTable("ProductTagJoinTable")`.

I'm wondering if you really want those mentioned three relationships. Or why do you expect the table name `ProductTag` belonging to the `ProductTag` entity? This table and entity isn't involved in your query at all.

**Edit**

Proposal to change your model: Your `ProductTag` entity doesn't contain any additional fields except the fields necessary for a many-to-many join table. Therefore I would map it as a pure many-to-many relationship. This means:

- Delete the `ProductTag` entity class from your model
- Delete the `ProductTags` navigation property from your `Tag` class
- Define the mapping in Fluent API as shown above (corresponding to a join table named `ProductTag` with two columns `ProductId` and `TagId` which form a composite primary key and are foreign keys to the `Product` and `Tag` table respectively)

As a result you will only have a single relationship (many-to-many between `Product` and `Tag`) and not three relationships and I expect that your query will work.

Comment: I had to take a bit of time to digest your answer, and then I started seeing more "Invalid object name dbo.TagProduct" errors in other areas of the app. Thats when your answer started to sink in. I ended removing navigation properties from Product and Tag. Had to restructure the query gdoron supplied to reflect the changes, and now it all works. I'll edit my question to show the final product. Thanks for your helpful (and detailed) response!

Comment: @JohnL: I see. Do you have additional scalar properties in your `ProductTag` entity? Otherwise you don't need it for many-to-many mapping between `Product` and `Tag`, but it will work as well :)